# Content type not supported issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

When i send with `Postman` a post request with JSON body (`application/json`) i got this error in `spring-mvc` (i am not using `spring boot`)

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
```

I tried all SO topics about this error but nothing works :(

I have include also the dependencies for `Jackson` in my `pom.xml` to map JSON objects into POJOs.

So why it keeps telling me `Content type 'application/json' not supported` !

My controller

```
@RestController
public class FooRest {
    // even with consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE it does not work
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String foo(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody FooBean bean) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"controllers"})
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { }
```

My `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

curl version

```
POST /MY-API HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 89859e26-813d-fb53-8726-57900f02207e

{ 
   //JSON OBJECT
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I changed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And it works finally :) can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 3):

By the way, `@PostMapping` is specialized version of `@RequestMapping` annotation that acts as a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

Without any change in the Spring configuration (`content-negotiation`), methods annotated with `@PostMapping` consumes and produces content in default media type i.e. `application/json`. The use of `consumes` and `produces` attributes of `@PostMapping` is only justified if you want to consumes and produces content in a different media type i.e. `application/xml`.

So, the following code should be fine to you:

```
@RestController
public class FooRest {

    @PostMapping("/api/foo")
    public String foo(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody FooBean bean) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And finally, you need the `accepts` header in the request as `application/json`

Can you share us the `curl` version of you request?

Comment: thanks for the explanations @AugustoJimenez but it's the same code as mine you just changed `@RequestMapping` with `@PostMapping`

Comment: Have you change default Spring configuration? The code is the same, but I tell you the default media type for mappings is application/json. So, theoretically the code is fine.

Comment: No i haven't change anything ... i posted the curl version from Postman .. do you think i import the incorrect jackson package in maven ??

Comment: Actually, you don't neet to add Jackson dependency to your Spring project because Spring uses Jackson internally for serializing and deserializing data in json format by default.

Comment: i think you are wrong on this check my question i solved the problem

Comment: Check the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-a-json-rest-service

Comment: i am not using spring boot that's why ... anyway you really help me with your explanations ;)